# X.org X Input driver issue: Linking xf86AddInputDriver function

Tags: linker-errors, xorg, xserver, rhel6

I am trying to write a mouse driver, on RedHat 6  linux, using the Xf86 API (X Input Driver). When I try to link the following code, I get an error stating:

```
undefined reference to `xf86AddInputDriver`
```

I don't know which library provides the function. Do any of you know? Is there a library that I need? I'm not sure if I have all the libraries or whether I have to build them. If I have to build them, what do I build them from the x.org source code?

```
static pointer XMouseDriver_plugin (pointer module,
                                    pointer aOptions,
                                    int * aErrMajPtr,
                                    int  * aErrMinPtr)
{
    xf86AddInputDriver(&fgInputDriverInitData,
               module,
               0);

    return (module);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Xorg input driver is a dynamic library that gets loaded by the Xorg server. The xf86AddInputDriver function is defined inside the Xorg server. Get the Xorg source code and check hw/xfree86/common/xf86Helper.c:

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/hw/xfree86/common/xf86Helper.c#n112

If you want to learn how to write an X server driver, there's a document called DESIGN:

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/hw/xfree86/doc/ddxDesign.xml